# How to put an Button Over an Image

Tags: html

In HTML5 is there a way to add a button on top of an image?

For instance here is my HTML,

```
<div><a href="http://www.website.com/family/">
     <img src="http://www.website.com/accordian.jpg" alt="image" />
</a></div>
```

Or is there a way to make part of an image link to another page, and another part of the image to link to a different page? I was thinking of modifying the image and putting in the button image, and making that part of the image link to a popup video.

Also how do I make this video appear in a popup window?

```
<video width="651" height="358" controls>
 <source src="www.website.com/accordian.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <object data="www.website.com/accordian.mp4" width="320" height="240">
 </object> 
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Html Area, you can set coordinates on the image and put a link on that area.
See example:

```
<img src ="http://www.website.com/accordian.jpg" alt="image"
usemap="#imagemap">

<map name="imagemap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,100" href="http://www.website.com/family/" alt="Link">
</map>
```